# Listing files from outside docker does not work but from within does

Tags: docker, shell, ls

What's wrong with the following statement ?

```
sudo docker exec myDockerName ls -lt /var/lib/myApp/data/myFolder/debian*.gz
```

this returns `No such file or directory`

but running the command being within the docker, returns the desired results

```
sudo docker exec -it myDockerName bash
ls -lt /var/lib/myApp/data/myFolder/debian*.gz
```

does `docker ls` work differently ?

Comment: can you try `sudo docker exec myDockerName bash -c "ls -lt /var/lib/myApp/data/myFolder/debian*.gz"` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that passing your arguments as a string can solve this issue, using the `-c` flag:

```
sudo docker exec myDockerName bash -c "ls -lt /var/lib/myApp/data/myFolder/debian*.gz"
```

Comment: @Veverke can you elaborate on your base image? which one are you using?

Comment: I am new to docker. I get a json response with the configuration. Some specific property you are interested in ?

Comment: @Veverke the first line in your `Dockerfile` - `FROM <base image>`